# Parse string as Json?

Tags: json

I have a json string but the format is strange

```
[[5706,[

[1132001,"Aston Villa","West Ham",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1966752,0],[1977724,1]],[],"","","","",64,63],
[1132002,"Blackburn","Everton",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1966753,0],[1977721,1]],[],"","","","",83,66],
[1132004,"Bolton","Fulham",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1966755,0],[1977727,1]],[],"","","","",88,85],
[1132005,"Chelsea","West Brom",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1966756,0],[1977712,1]],[],"","","","",503,94],
[1132006,"Liverpool","Arsenal",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1966757,0],[1977733,1]],[],"","","","",59,58],
[1132007,"Man Utd","Newcastle",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1966758,0],[1977730,1]],[],"","","","",19,70],
[1132008,"Sunderland","Birmingham",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1966759,0],[1977715,1]],[],"","","","",60,86],
[1132009,"Tottenham","Man City",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1966760,0],[1977739,1]],[],"","","","",62,77],
[1132010,"Wolves","Stoke City",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1966761,0],[1977718,1]],[],"","","","",81,342],
[1146485,"Wigan","Blackpool",5706,'2010-08-14T15:00:00.0000000',[[1998244,0],[1998321,1]],[],"","","","",350,328]],

[[1015824,8],[1035605,126]]]]
```

So, How can i parse and extract it value?

Thanks

Comment: Parse it in JavaScript you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just eval it using whatever library is relevant to the language you're parsing it into. The format is a list of values and lists - so from the resulting structure you'll just need to traverse the lists to get to the pieces that you're interested in. Without more context, I can't provide any brilliant insight into what the values mean in those lists, but doing a little googlin' digging makes me thing you're looking at data related to football club tickets and/or games.

Comment: I'm sure you could if it can parse JSON (which it looks like it was built to do). I'm afraid that I can't rattle off the C# code to walk through lists of lists off the top of my head - but it should work just fine.